Extracting XML data in Snowflake Table
I have a column in a table in Snowflake that contains XML data. I need to extract this data into a table but I'm getting issues with only getting 'null' values when parsing the XML. An example of the XML...
<Req>
  <R>
    <PM>
      <PC>TU</PC>
      <PD>CAP</PD>
      <EN>5364</EN>
      <H>468413541</H>
      <Haz></Haz>
      <GW>0.3</GW>
      <GWU>K</GWU>
      <LC></LC>
      <DC>526543135464</DC>
      <CO>CN</CO>
      <B>Pro</B>
      <Col>RED</Col>
      <S>S</S>
      <GI></GI>
      <SN></SN>
      <M></M>
    </PM>
  </R>
  <R>
    <PM>
      <PC>TU</PC>
      <PD>CAP</PD>
      <EN>54654</EN>
      <H>6645153</H>
      <Haz></Haz>
      <GW>0.3</GW>
      <GWU>K</GWU>
      <LC></LC>
      <DC>546543134164</DC>
      <CO>CN</CO>
      <B>Pro</B>
      <Col>OCEAN</Col>
      <S>S</S>
      <GI></GI>
      <SN></SN>
      <M></M>
    </PM>
  </R>
</Req>

I am trying to get everything within the PM part.
Initially I have tried the below to get the PC part but get nulls.
SELECT
    f.value:Req:R:PM:PC::string AS PC,
FROM Table,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => PARSE_XML(data)::VARIANT) AS f

